# Why the request originated from JETTY server on node1 providing response on node2?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, response, shibboleth

I am using **Jetty-6.1.19** server. There is a "Shibboleth access model" integrated in my project which provides access to paid articles in a manner such that institutes which have purchased licenses for journals get access for the articles after logging in. We have this setup on 2 nodes.

The issue I am facing is that when I am requesting on node1, the response in going to node2. While on node2, its all working fine, i.e. when I am requesting from node2, the response is coming properly on node2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Please post a MCVE so we can help you, at the moment it's anyones guess what is going on](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2010, consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Shibboleth requires that the whole authentication process be completed on the same node. You probably need to configure your load balancer to use sticky sessions, server affinity, etc.

Once the authn process is complete then, assuming your configuration is proper, the user can be directed to either node to get an AuthnResponse.

Comment: I understand, that the entire authentication process should completed on same node, but that is exactly, where its failing, just wondering what should be the cause of this redirection from node 1 to node 2, some configuration in load balancer? (If yes, then I am going to access them for first time)